# GLIBC 2.14 installation error: forced unwind support is required - RHEL 7.5

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, redhat

I have upgraded my RHEL OS from 6.7 to 7.5. After upgrading, I found some issues when trying to run `yum`. Below are the details.

```
# yum repolist

There was a problem importing one of the Python modules                                                                                                                       
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:                                                                                                                   

/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1)                                                                                        

Please install a package which provides this module, or                                                                                                                       
verify that the module is installed correctly.                                                                                                                                

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the                                                                                                                         
current version of Python, which is:                                                                                                                                          
2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug  9 2016, 06:11:56)                                                                                                                                     
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)]                                                                                                                                       

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to                                                                                                                       
the yum faq at:                                                                                                                                                               
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

---

After getting this error, I just installed python2.7 and GLIBC 2.14. But when I am trying to install GLIBC 2.14 from my current GLIBC version 2.12, it is throwing some error. Below are the steps that I am using to install GLIBC 2.14:

1. `tar xvfz glibc-2.14.tar.gz`
2. `cd glibc-2.14`
3. `mkdir build`
4. `cd build`
5. `../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14`
6. `make`
7. `sudo make install`
8. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

In step5, I am getting error. Below are the details:

```
# ../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14

checking for forced unwind support... no                                                                                                                                
configure: error: forced unwind support is required
```

I am unaware of this error "unwind support is required".Please let me know how to setup/install forced unwind in Redhat 7.5.

Comment: The proper procedure to upgrade from 6 to 7 is detailed at [How do I upgrade from Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 to Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/637583).  Step 1 is to run yum update which would've brought your system from 6.7 up to 6.9 before attempting to upgrade to 7.  Upgrading from anything other than the latest version of 6.x is not supported.

Comment: Yes you right, first i have upgraded it to 6.9 by using yum upgrade command. Then, i started to upgrade from 6.9 to 7.5.I have not followed the steps from the link which is given by you.But I followed from different website with the correct procedure like I downloaded the ISO image and mounted it to my folder and then copied all the content from the folder and then created the repo for rhel7 in yum repository and then used few upgration command. My ec2 server upgraded to 7.5 successfully.but still getting the above error.

Comment: Now the problem is I have already upgraded it to 7.5 and shared the details of the server to client. Anyhow I have to resolve the above issue.

Comment: Time to call Red Hat support.